# full calendar(angular-ui event change background when event limit=true

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I don't know how to do the event background-color change when i have limit event (example: i want to draw the event with background color, i don't want text "*+2 more*") ;

`class fc-more` is the div with the events.

**Configuration:**

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            firstDay:1,
            height: 'auto',
            editable: true,

                eventLimit: true,
                 eventLimitText: "",


                            views: {
                                month: {
                                   eventLimit: 1
                                }},

            titleFormat: {
                     month: 'MMMM'
            },
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
             eventRender:  function (event, element) {
                        element = angular.element('fc-more');
                element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                debugger;
        if(event.color =="#3985AA")
        {
            element.css('background-color', '#3985AA');
        }
        if(event.color =="#43AF89")
        {
            element.css('background-color', '#43AF89');
        }
        if(event.color =="#FFC900")
        {
            element.css('background-color', '#FFC900');
        }

    },
```

**HTTP Ajax**

```
    $scope.eventSources = [

    ];
    ajax.sendApiRequest({}, "GET", "eventosusuario", false).then(function (response) {
        angular.forEach(response.data, function (evento) {
            evento.start = new Date(evento.fecha);
            evento.allDay = true;
            evento.end = new Date(evento.fecha);
            evento.title = evento.titulo;
            evento.color= "#3985AA";
            evento.textColor="#FFFFFF";
            evento.url="#/app/evento/"+evento.nid;

        })
        $scope.eventSources.push(response.data);

    }, function (error) {
        _showPopUp('error', 'error');
    });
```

Comment: `backgroundColor` is correct properties, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i don't understand you!! @RuhulAmin..... where i change my code, please!!! i need change (+2 more text per background color)